Can not override body style after migraton to v5 antd
Antd version: 5.10.3
React version: 16.8.6
I try to override my body style after migration to v5 antd
But it does not work
I have such code and font for this code should be from my index.scss file:


body {
  font-family: "DinPro", Tahoma, serif !important;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
<div className="field__item-title">
 <b>{itemCaption}</b>
</div>



But in my project i have this:
How can i override my styles?


You should probably look into disabling that .css-dev-only-do-not-override class instead of trying to override it (it says "do not override" in the class name lol). So you might want to understand why its there and what is for before you go about adding a bunch of !important to your css. I did a brief Google search and found this post which might help you. Good luck!
